# Unity AdMob reward ad runs normally, but gets a NullReferenceException on android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, nullreferenceexception, logcat

I implemented Admob rewarded ads and they work perfectly in unity, but when building and running the game on my Android the ad doesn't run.

[This is the LogCat error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5rTb.png)

This is the code when I run the `WatchAd(int ID)` the game seems to get stuck on `rewardedAd.IsLoaded()`

```
private RewardedAd rewardedAd;
public void Start()
{
    MobileAds.Initialize(HandleInitComplete);
    rewardPopUp.SetActive(false);
    CreateAndLoadRewardedAd();
}
private void HandleInitComplete(GoogleMobileAds.Api.InitializationStatus status) =>
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    appID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
    appID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";
#else
    appID = "Probably Pc";
#endif
public void WatchAd(int ID)
{
    Debug.Log("Ran WatchAD");
    if (rewardedAd.IsLoaded())
    {
        Debug.Log("IsLoaded");
        rewardedAd.Show();
        rewardPopUp.SetActive(true);
        AdType = ID;
    }
    else { 
        CreateAndLoadRewardedAd(); 
        Debug.Log("Can't Load");}
}
public void CreateAndLoadRewardedAd()
{
    rewardedAd = new RewardedAd(appID);

    rewardedAd.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleRewardedAdFailedToLoad;
    rewardedAd.OnAdFailedToShow += HandleRewardedAdFailedToShow;
    rewardedAd.OnUserEarnedReward += HandleUserEarnedReward;

    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    rewardedAd.LoadAd(request);
}
public void HandleRewardedAdFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
{
    switch (timesFailed)
    {
        case 0:
            Invoke("CreateAndLoadRewardedAd()", 60);
            break;
        case 1:
            Invoke("CreateAndLoadRewardedAd()", 120);
            break;
        default:
            Invoke("CreateAndLoadRewardedAd()", 240);
            break;
    }
    timesFailed++;
}
```

I Have tried doing this with test ads and my own AdMob ad IDs, also added my device as a test device.
there are no errors displayed when i run it with unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed my issue by Force Resolving:

Assets > External Dependency Manager > Android Resolver > Force Resolve

Answer (score 0):

In this part

```
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    appID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
    appID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917";
#else
    appID = "Probably Pc";
#endif
```

It should be should Ad unit ID not App ID. Check this [Admob Unity tutorial](https://vionixstudio.com/2022/03/11/google-admob-tutorial-for-unity/) if you need more help.

Comment: changed it to my Ad unit ID, and also changed Ads Settings to my App ID, but the same error appears

Comment: Post your updated code and screenshot of Admob settings window in Unity. Just double check your AD unit ID and App id from Admob website.

Comment: while the variable was named appID the ID itself was still correct, so the error was exactly the same, but I did fix the problem by force resolving.